# Search result for - "xyz" displayed when searched for "xzy"

Tags: google-search-console

I have a new website http://www.xzy.com . 
When I search on google with the keyword `xzy`, then another website with similar pronunciation is displayed in the search results and my website is displayed in "Search instead for" part. How can I show proper results on google ?

EDIT:
After around 2 months of working on my website i have found that google has started to recognize "XZY" as new word in spite of having tough competition with XYZ. Now instead of showing "Search instead of" google is displaying proper normal result.

Comment: It shows up second in results for me. https://www.google.com/search?q=thotlabs#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&nfpr=1&q=thotlabs&sa=X&ei=WZsSUZyANeeCyAG0koCACA&ved=0CDEQvgUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41934586,d.aWc&fp=dc5a2a82f5fd8500&biw=1303&bih=659

Comment: This questions should perhaps be moved to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LoSauer : How can i move question to webmaster ?

Comment: @RajatSharma Admins may move it in a democratic vote. Meanwhile you can ask your question there.

Comment: ok.. thanx.. I would also i like to move this question to the proper category.. Sorry if any inconvenience created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until your site is more popular, Google will always think that "thotlabs" is a mistyping of "thorlabs." When your site is searched enough, Google will recognize both as acceptable spellings and not recommend a different spelling.

In the meantime, register your site on [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) so Google is more aware of your site and you can see data on how Google is indexing your site.